# Fais attention, Faites attention

Tags: expressions, vouvoiement

Bonjour,

J'entends souvent ''faites attention'', bien distinguable de ''fais attention'', on entend clairement le T phonique.

Si les gens disent ''faites attention'', c'est une forme de politesse ou c'est parce qu'ils veulent adresser plusieurs personnes?

J'ai peur de dire ''faites attention'' à quelqu'un si c'est pour adresser plusieurs personnes au lieu de politesse.

Merci.

Comment: One can use "faites attention" for either reason (or both).  If you are on "vous" terms with someone, then it is okay to say "faites attention" to a single person.  (Although it is a slightly aggressive phrase, so if you're nervous about how the person might take it, maybe it would be better to choose an alternate formulation, e.g. *Je vous remercie de votre attention ... Puis-je vous demander votre attention ... Permettez-nous d'attirer votre attention sur etc.*)  Note: if time is of the essence (someone is about to step out into traffic, perhaps), then you can omit the verb: *Attention!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Faites attention* s'emploie quand on s'adresse à plusieurs personnes ou bien quand on s'adresse à une seule personne de manière polie.  Par exemple :

- Faites attention, Madame, vous oubliez votre portefeuille.

Answer (score 1):

Cela dépend de ce que l'on a besoin de dire ; si l'on veut signifier à plusieurs personnes de faire attention, la formule convient et on l'utilise sans changement dans la prononciation ; s'il ne s'agit que d'une personne avec laquelle on n'entretient pas de relation à un niveau familier on l'utilise alors parce que c'est aussi la forme de politesse et la prononciation est strictement la même.